# Hibernate search faceting, how to return facet query Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-search, facet

I have query and getting facets by this query. But how Can I add selected facet to next query from front end ?

```
     FacetingRequest categoryFacetingRequest = qBuilder.facet()
            .name("categoryFaceting").onField("distr").discrete()
            .orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.COUNT_DESC).includeZeroCounts(false)
            .createFacetingRequest();
    FacetManager facetManager = fullTextQuery.getFacetManager();
    facetManager.enableFaceting(categoryFacetingRequest);

    List<Facet> facets = facetManager.getFacets("categoryFaceting");
```

List of facets I attach as model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuimg you're using jsp. You need to build link with all the old parameters used to show the current results plus a new one narrowing the query.

Example:

```
<c:forEach items="${facets}" var="narrowingFacetParam" varStatus="loop">
    <li>    
        <a href='
            <c:url value="search">
                <c:param name="oldQueryParam1" value="${oldQueryParam1value}"/>
                <c:param name="oldQueryParam2" value="${oldQueryParam2value}"/>
                ...
                <c:param name="narrowingFacetParam" value="${narrowingFacetParam.value}"/>
            </c:url>
        '>${narrowingFacetParam.name}</a>

    </li>                               
</c:forEach>
```

Of course you have to build your query the way it can accept any number of narrowing parameters (example: narrow the results to match a given price range and a given category).